# Numerous asynchronous functions should wait for completion of first

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, wait

Consider the following setup, regarding asynchronous functions:

```
Client.prototype.auth = function(callback) {
    //authenticate the client
    //run callback
};

Client.prototype.get = function() {
    this.auth(function(){
        //run the rest of this `get` function
    }
};
```

- The `get` function is called numerous times through an eventlistener, and this event fires only once
- The very first `get` should start the authentication which stays valid for every subsequent calls
- The authentication function is takes a couple of seconds to complete
- Every subsequent `get` call does not need to reauthenticate because it is still valid because of the first function call
- Every subsequent `get` call should only be run after the client is authenticated. If it is not authenticated it should wait for the authentication to finish

The point is to prevent 10 `get` calls to fire 10 `auth` calls. Whenever the 1st `auth` function gets called, the other 9 `get` calls should wait for it to finish and then carry on with the rest of the `get` function (while being authenticated)

I cant get my head around this. I tried to keep this example as simple as possible

Comment: Consider using [js-csp](https://github.com/ubolonton/js-csp)

Comment: well thats helpful i rather make something small to solve this issue then to include a whole library

Comment: You'll want to use promises. Caching asynchronous results is trivial with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think solution for you is [caching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/51658). Make a cache that will hold value `isUserAutheniticated` and `isAuthenitcationProcess` and when you need to call `auth` just check if user is authenticated and if not call it. Inside `auth` subscribe callback, check if authentication process is open if not do authentication set and call all registered callbacks. Globallist is not cleanest option to implement [Observable pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) so you can do it [in other way](http://bumbu.ru/javascript-observer-publish-subscribe-pattern/)

Here is my idea:

```
var isAuthenticated = false;
var isAuthenticatioProcess = false;
var authenticationCallbacks = [];
Client.prototype.auth = function(callback) {
    authenitcationCallbacks.push(callback);
    if (isAuthenticonProcess) {           
       return;
    }
    //authenticate
    authenitcationCallbacks.forEach(function(call) {
        call();
    });
    authenitcationCallbacks = [];
    isAuthenticonProcess = false;
    isAuthenticated = true;
};

Client.prototype.get = function() {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        this.auth(function(){
            //run the rest of this `get` function
        }
    } else {
        function(){
            //run the rest of this `get` function
        }
    }
};
```

If you could use [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10291183/1387612) answer

Comment: "Inside auth check if authentication process is open if true wait on this variable until it ends periodically checking status (busy waiting), to prevent it you can keep list of subscribers that should be notified inside auth's callback" that part confuses me, how would you loop that 'periodically checking' thing and how do you callback all the `get` functions? I have [link](http://underscorejs.org/) available if that might help