# How to Select Text in an Element (akin to highlighting with your mouse) on newly created ajax content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the `selectText` function from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/784637

However when I called this function immediately after an ajax request on the newly created element:

`selectText('some-newly-added-element')`

I get the following error in firebug

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_OBJECT_ERR: Parameter is not an object
[Break On This Error]   

range.selectNodeContents(text);
```

Note that I am able to call this function after the ajax request on the same element like so

```
$('#container').on('click', '#some-newly-added-element', function(){
   selectText('some-newly-added-element');            
});
```

Is there a way to call this function immediately after the ajax request is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: `Is there a way to call this function immediately after the ajax request is done?`

Do you mean after success of the ajax `success`. *or* http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

*or* This should help: [Execute function after all ajax .load() requests are finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502828/jquery-execute-function-after-all-ajax-load-requests-are-finished)

Hope this fits the cause `:)`

**Sample**

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.html_url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        doSomething();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this, so using your example I do `result.html(html);         selectText('some-newly-added-element'); ` and it still doesn't work.  note that `#some-newly-added-element` is part of the `html` response

Comment: Hmmm @user784637 take a look in here man: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502828/jquery-execute-function-after-all-ajax-load-requests-are-finished ; lemme know how it goes! `:)~

Answer (score 1):

use `complete` callback which will trigger after ajax call

```
  $.ajax({

  complete: function(){
       selectText('some-newly-added-element');
      }

   });
```

Documentation for ajax event: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events